# Filtering on False column value returns with True

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, mariadb

I have two tables that I am doing a left join on where the second table has a bit column. The filter returns columns where that bit is False. *However* when I check that value later inside a loop it is showing as true.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, Boolean, ForeignKey, or_
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm.exc import NoResultFound
# from sqlalchemy.exc import DataError
Base = declarative_base()

class BoardGame(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'game_detail'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    description = Column(String)
    process = relationship('Process', uselist=False, back_populates='game_detail')

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<BoardGame(id='{}', name='{}', description='{}'".format(
            self.id, self.name, self.description
        )

class Process(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'process'
    game_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('game_detail.id'), primary_key=True)
    description_bigram = Column(Boolean)
    game_detail = relationship('BoardGame', back_populates='process')

sa_engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://bgg:blahblahblah@localhost:49000/boardgamegeek?charset=utf8mb4', pool_recycle=3600)
session = Session(bind=sa_engine)

# Set the scripts execution range of data
maximum_games_to_process = 1

for game in session.query(BoardGame.id, Process.description_bigram).join(Process, isouter=True).filter(Process.description_bigram.is_(False)).limit(maximum_games_to_process):
    print('description_bigram', type(game.description_bigram), game.description_bigram)
    print(game)
```

Running the above gets me

```
description_bigram <class 'bool'> True
(1, True)
```

But looking at the data in HeidiSQL shows me otherwise.

```
game_id;description_bigram
1;0
2;1
3;0
4;0
5;1
```

Here is the create code for the process table as shown in HeidiSQL

```
CREATE TABLE `process` (
    `game_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `description_bigram` BIT(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`game_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK__GAME_ID_DESCRIPTION` FOREIGN KEY (`game_id`) REFERENCES `game_detail` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

I have seen some posts elude to SQLAlchemy's issues with Boolean columns and [people have change their tables and code to work with integers instead](https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/issues/567) (Link is only similar to my situation). I am sure that would work but I have other programs that work just fine with Bit columns and table Boolean definitions so I am not sure why this one isn't working. Is there something under the hood I can look at?

This is the query created by SQLAlchemy

```
SELECT game_detail.id AS game_detail_id, process.description_bigram AS process_description_bigram
FROM game_detail LEFT OUTER JOIN process ON game_detail.id = process.game_id
WHERE process.description_bigram IS false
```

I have tried a few things to try and get the column to register its correct value and I just keep ending up with it being true.

Python is version 3.6.5; SQLAlchemy is 1.2.7; 10.3.13-MariaDB

Comment: Show us the SQL query generated by SQLAlchemy.

Comment: @RickJames I have updated the question with the SQLAlchemyQuery

Comment: Either change `FALSE` to `NULL` or get rid of `LEFT`.